# Chat not always HTTPS

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, ssl

Sometimes in the chat rooms, I see a warning icon instead of the normal green lock in Firefox.

[image: HTTPS warning icon on Firefox]

Looking through the "More Information" area, I see that the site is trying to load `http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackexchange/img/apple-touch-icon.png`

[image: The culprit]

I've tried clearing my cache, but that didn't change anything.
So I've been popping in and out of chat rooms on various sites, and it *seems* that the issue only appears in chat rooms that were automatically created and imported from comments.

---

Now, I've been told in the comments that HTTPS on chat isn't really supported yet.  This is fine.  What is strange to me is that the only thing loaded that is not HTTPS is this single `apple-touch-icon.png` (with the main SE logo).  Firefox states that the associated text for this icon is "Feeds".

If the page were to use the site-specific `apple-touch-icon` (which is already loaded, as shown by the next line in my screenshot), there would be no plain HTTP connections.  Why do we need to load both the site-specific and general SE icons?  Why do we need to load the general SE icon over plain HTTP?

Comment: If you reached the https version via link inside SE that's the bug, all the links to chat should be to http:// only. If you changed the URL yourself to https, or using extensions that do it for you, it is not SE problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The ones with the warning icon came from the "Let us continue this discussion in chat." comments, with the HTTPS Everywhere add-on both enabled and disabled. But my search seems to have been incomplete; see also https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/32504 — it is the image next to the word "Feeds" that loads HTTP

Comment: Ok, it took me some time but I found the source. It is the avatar of the Feed user, for example [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds).  Looks like all avatars from users or protocol relative, except the system user (those with a negative userid) for that Feed. If anything, that should be fixed.

Comment: So worth reporting the “Let us continue this discussion in chat” use protocol relative link, leading the users to broken https chat, which is not much better than broken link. Please do this in a new, separate, bug report.

Comment: @rene well, maybe ping Nick in comment or chat, don't think this one is worth its own bug report. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I pinged the bluefeet .. nice knowing you ...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Will it take time for the protocol-relative links to work for system users? I'm still getting mixed-content warning for now, but I don't know where all the various layers of caching are. And where might I find this Nick, to mention the protocol-relative chat links?

Comment: @rene but the blue one ain't no dev.... all she can do is ping Nick... oh well. :)

Comment: @Fox Nick might be available in the Tavern, and you can also leave a comment under his answer on the linked dupe. Fixing the avatar URL might very well be more complicated than it sounds, they are using complex systems behind the scenes to generate the URLs.

Comment: @ShadowWizard but Bluefeet has mod powers and can change avatars of users. I'm pretty sure they can fix that.