# What's the point of The Stack Exchange Network chat room? (and a bug around how people end up there)

Tags: bug, chat

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11254/

As I understand, this is "the default chat room" of the entire SE site, but it doesn't seem like it's in use by anyone other than random confused passerby users. How do they end up there? When you leave a room by clicking "leave", the internet currents may bring you (quite consistently in my case) to [a specific version of this page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=people) where you will see the StackExchange logo, and not whatever logo of the site you were just on. If you click the tabs like "site", "all", "mine", the logo might change, and the chat room listing along with it. The thing is, the url stays the same (apart from the arguments which shouldn't affect the view like that), but the look of the page changes (probably due to a bug).

Start at this url: https://chat.stackexchange.com and you will see this (this is my view because A&M is my main chat site):

[image]

It appears we're in the tab "Site", sorted by "people". Let's click that "people" link again, shall we? This is what happens:

[image]

We're in that bugged view! But let's click that "people" link once more, since it's full of surprises:

[image]

The url got weird now! This doesn't look like intended behavior to me. (further clicking "people" doesn't change anything at this point)

Comment: Chat has always used `Referer` info to determine which site you belong to; it started *also* using query parameters for the purpose, but those aren't wholly reliable.

Comment: Related question [Problem in redirecting link while leaving a chat room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296841/problem-in-redirecting-link-while-leaving-a-chat-room).

Comment: Until recently, leaving a chat room always took me back to my favorites list, just like I wanted.  Now I keep getting a page with only that one SE room and I have to click on the tab to get the view I want.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It is because the work of https has been started in chat rooms too. Chat was accessible in http too until recently but now it is not available. When https is complete, then there will beno problem. See the linked question in the above comment.